# array from input attribute jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

need to check each input if it has attribute inArray then show this input filed else hide

My html code

```
<label class="priceswrapper" tour_type="reg, div">Price
<input  name="adult_cost"  type="text"/>
</lable>
<label class="priceswrapper" tour_type="reg, div">Price
<input  name="kids_cost"  type="text"/>
</lable>
<label class="priceswrapper" tour_type="div">Price
<input  name="intro_dive"  type="text"/>
</lable>
<label class="priceswrapper" tour_type="div">Price
<input  name="pro_dive"  type="text"/>
</lable>
<label class="priceswrapper" tour_type="qud">Price
<input  name="quad_price"  type="text"/>
</lable>
```

jQuery Code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('.priceswrapper').each(function(){
    var data = 'reg';
    var types = [$(this).attr('tour_type')];
    if ($.inArray(data, types) !== -1) {
        $(this).show();
            }else {
               $(this).hide();
               }
  });   
});
```

Comment: Note that you have typos, it's `label` not `lable` !

Comment: Use `data-type` instead of `tour_type`

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Also note that you only have an array containing the entire string from the attribute, it doesn't magically split, you should be using `var types = $(this).attr('tour_type').split(/,\s+/);`

Comment: forgot `$(this).attr('tour_type').replace(' ', '').split(',')`

Comment: my question is this is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      $('.priceswrapper').each(function(){
        var data = 'reg';
        var types = $(this).attr('tour_type').split(',');// you should get string fron here.
        console.log(types);
        if ($.inArray(data, types) !== -1) {
            $(this).show();
                }else {
                   $(this).hide();
                   }
      });   
    });


</script>
<label class="priceswrapper" tour_type="reg, div">Price
<input  name="adult_cost"  type="text"/>
</lable>
<label class="priceswrapper" tour_type="reg, div">Price
<input  name="kids_cost"  type="text"/>
</lable>
<label class="priceswrapper" tour_type="div">Price
<input  name="intro_dive"  type="text"/>
</lable>
<label class="priceswrapper" tour_type="div">Price
<input  name="pro_dive"  type="text"/>
</lable>
<label class="priceswrapper" tour_type="qud">Price
<input  name="quad_price"  type="text"/>
</lable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hpbf529z/)

**HTML**

```
<label class="priceswrapper" data-type="reg, div">Price
    <input  name="adult_cost"  type="text"/>
</label>
<label class="priceswrapper" data-type="reg, div">Price
    <input  name="kids_cost"  type="text"/>
</label>
<label class="priceswrapper" data-type="div">Price
    <input  name="intro_dive"  type="text"/>
</label>
<label class="priceswrapper" data-type="div">Price
    <input  name="pro_dive"  type="text"/>
</label>
<label class="priceswrapper" data-type="qud">Price
    <input  name="quad_price"  type="text"/>
</label>
```

**jQuery**

```
    var data = 'reg';
    $('.priceswrapper').each(function(idx, obj) {
        var types = $(this).data('type').split(/,\s+/);
        console.log(types);
        console.log($.inArray(data, types));
        if ($.inArray(data, types) !== -1) {
            $(obj).show();
        } else {
            $(obj).hide();
        }
    });
```